# Atomic bonding forces -

Tags: atomic-physics, physical-chemistry

I was watching IBM's short film called `How to move an atom` and it got me thinking the following:

Which element should one use as a surface in order to get the lowest friction when one atom has to move over a 2D sheet of atoms of the element?

Comment: think about ice, it is  the temperature that makes the difference, i.e. the crystal lattice forms on which things slide

Comment: I'm a little confused with your question, are you talking about one-to-one atom 'friction', or one atom vs a perfectly flat surface, or two perfectly flat surfaces, or friction between rough surfaces?

Comment: @annav I see...

Comment: @user190081 I am talking about one-to-one atom 'friction'